# How to force all the Threads to use the latest value of a variable without having to use volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a multi threaded application in which threads use a global variable. And this variable is updated only once in the main Thread.

What would be the best way to make sure that all the other threads take the latest value when it is updated?

Defining this variable as volatile would be a hit on the performance as I need to update it only once in days.

Comment: Put the assignment in a `synchronized` block.

Comment: @AndyTurner And is that more efficient for reads?

Comment: The reads aren't in the synchronized block. Only the assignment. You'd need to pick the monitor appropriately.

Comment: Does this guarantee that all the Threads will have access to the latest value of the variable after the assignment is done. What do mean by picking the monitor appropriately?

Comment: If the reads aren't synchronized on the same lock as the write, you have no visibility guarantee. @awsome: you're probably prematurely optimizing, which is the root of all evil. Use a volatile, or an AtomicXxx, and start worrying about optimization if you have a performance problem. It's very unlikely that you have one due to a volatile read.

Comment: The update happens once in days but the reads are done millions of times everyday on this variable. So i think the my usecase is very valid

Comment: Define it as volatile and take the hit. Or else accept wrong answers. You can get the wrong answer in zero time, if that's your objective. Decide.

Answer (score 0):

Declare you variable as `volatile` and you are done.

---

... But it is true that it is possible to optimize access to your variable in some cases. You want to be 100% sure that no other variables share cache line with your variable. Why? Because if no sharing occurs, then copy of latest version of variable is available in CPU caches of all cores in **S** (shared) state. Reading this variable is fast as if it was not declared as `volatile`. But if there are other data sharing cache line with your variable AND this other data is modified frequently (e.g. each microsecond), than threads wishing to read your variable are blocked while most recent value of your variable is transfered from cache of CPU from which this another data was updated.

To demonstrate above scenarios, here the program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CacheLineSharing {

    static class Holder {
        volatile long pad0;
        volatile long pad1;
        volatile long pad2;
        volatile long pad3;
        volatile long pad4;
        volatile long pad5;
        volatile long pad6; // either pad6 or pad7 shares cache line with x
        volatile long x = INIT_VALUE;
        volatile long pad7;
        volatile long pad8;
        volatile long pad9;
        volatile long pad10;
        volatile long pad11;
        volatile long pad12;
        volatile long pad13;

        volatile long pad14; // definitely in different cache line than x
    }

    static final int INIT_VALUE = 0;
    static final int START_VALUE = 1;
    static final int FINISH_VALUE = 2;

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        Holder holder;
        MyThread(Holder holder) {
            this.holder = holder;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (holder.x != START_VALUE);

            long cycles = 0;
            while (holder.x != FINISH_VALUE) {
                cycles++;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("cycles=%d", cycles));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Holder holder = new Holder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            new MyThread(holder).start();
        }

        long ts = System.nanoTime();
        holder.x = START_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            //holder.pad6 = i;
            holder.pad14 = i;
        }
        holder.x = FINISH_VALUE;
        long nanoes = System.nanoTime() - ts;
        System.out.println(String.format("millis=%d", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(nanoes)));
    }
}
```

Our target variable is `x` and we measure how fast reading its value is. In the first case we are constantly updating `pad6` variable (it has 6 in 7 chances of sharing cache line with `x`):

```
millis=4317
cycles=584637722
cycles=655006968
cycles=1214910177
cycles=1133123641
```

~280K iteration per second for fastest thread

Now the same program updates `pad14` variable which does not share cache line with `x` (modern Intel CPUs have cache lines of 64 bytes = 8 java longs):

```
cycles=1857323945
cycles=2034309531
cycles=1820202891
millis=1363
cycles=2083430201
```

~1335K iterations per second even for slowest thread.

4.75 times faster!

So, if you`re totally mad about optimization, pad your variable 7 longs before and 7 longs after.

Comment: Avoiding false sharing does not immediately guarantee visibility across threads, even for a single writer. Padding the variable does not in any way ensure that changes to it will be immediately propagated to the cache subsystem, as opposed to being kept in the store buffer. Also keep in mind that padding with a hardcoded number of `long`s is not portable (POWER8 uses 128-byte l1d cache lines) - if you are on Java 8, just use `@Contended`. And if you are not using a tool like JMH, it's hard to say that you're not measuring any of a number of unrelated and subtle side effects.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, if we are talking about modern Intel`s CPUs, then changes are immediately visible. Exceptions from this rule are: 1) using SIMD instructions (which may buffer results in store buffer); 2) using memory address ranges explicitly marked with memory type with weaker guarantees than write-back cacheable. (Of course, this solution is not portable to other architectures. The problem usually is that portability contradicts performance.)